# Gasteria leaf thinning

Tags: plant-health, roots

This is a common problem I encounter. What causes this to happen even if the roots look healthy?
[image: thin_leaves]

It may happen during mid to late summer, at the peak of the summer's heat . Leaves thinning and appearing like cardboard. Summer dormancy may or may not break, but growth is stunted for sure.

This is Gasteria 'Sakura Fuji', and it was plumper and healthier for quite a while. I took this plant out of its pot just today and inspected the roots. There were just very few dead roots. Most are healthy and don't suffer from any pest or disease. I trimmed the long ones, took-out any dead roots I saw, and repotted it.

The old potting mix was 50/50 peat/coarse sand (used for swimming pools sand filters). The new mix is made up of equal parts coconut & Perlite.

Answer (score 1):

Plants loose water through transpiration, water is released through the pores in the surface of the leaf.  Gasteria have large leaves, so they have a greater amount of surface area.

Thinning of Gasteria leaves is normal sign of not enough water. It makes perfect sense that it happened at the peak of summer.  You are waiting too long/keeping your soil too dry.   They can handle quite a bit of water in the summer.   I need to water every other day in summer, but I do use a less absorbent mixture 24/76 Brown matter/drainage.  You may need to water as much as every three days, but don't go by days go by the dryness of the soil.

When you do water, give your plants a good soak, either from above or below.  If watering from below you probably need the water level to reach 1/4-1/2 of the soil level.  This depends on how good your soil is at wicking water.  You may not need that deep, since sand mixtures tend to be better at wicking.

If you water from below, every other month you will need to water from above to wash out the salt that build up in the soil.  Salt from your water, fertiliser, even natural calcium and magnesium in the clay of the pot.

If you worry about over-watering then use a bamboo skewer to help you decide how wet the soil is.  Insert a bamboo barbecue skewer into your soil.  When you think it is time to water check the skewer, look at the colour difference of the dry part compared to the that was in the soil.  Also touch it, feel how wet it is. Depending on how damp it is is the time to water or not.  You do not accomplish anything by letting the soil go completely dry in summer.  In winter you can let it go completely dry, even leaving it dry for a few days, but the leaves will start to dry out.  Water as soon as you see them starting to deflate in winter.   In summer water as soon as the soil goes dry, but not bone dry.  Never let the leaves start to thin in the summer.

How to inflate your leaves in winter; Water as soon as the soil goes bone dry, do not wait days.  If you water right away and give them a soak the leaves will slowly start to plump up.   To inflate leaves in summer; Keep the soil consistently moist, not wet.  This will give them the water they need to plump-up, but not too much to rot the roots.

Comment: I'll try to increase watering few days after repotting. This winter precipitations were too low so far. Since that's their rainy season I will will not let it dry for too long..

Comment: It is advisable to not water for the first week.   This gives any damage done during the process time to heal.  Then give it a good soak.   I am not sure what part of the world you live the growing season is not the same as it is in their climate.  Meaning Gasteria will grow when they get the right amount of rain and warmth, even in the summer.  They will never go fully dormant during the summer, so you still need to water it in the summer.  You might be surprised by the growth you will get if you do water more.